# Did Trolls develop their own technology?

Tags: david-weber, apocalypse-troll

It seems like the neuron whip is a weapon uniquely suited to Trolls:

> She shuddered at the thought of the whip. **The Kangas had rejected it as inefficient, but the Trolls loved it.** It went after nerve tissue and incapacitated its victims instantly, but death took long, terrible minutes, and it was lethal up to twenty meters from its point of focus. Its effects were far slower at the greater range, but they were no less certain or agonizing. Not even a Thuselah could survive a direct hit, and they had a less than even chance of surviving a near miss.

It is clear (both from textual analysis - and the in-universe canon from quote above) that it was rather poor choice of weapon to practical and logical Kangas.

Does that mean that Trolls developed their own weapons? Because it seems unlikely that Kangas would even bother developing something that illogical.

Comment: Couldn't you also read that as the Kangas invented it, found its lack of range or something else unacceptable, and didn't want it, but the Trolls kept using it?

Comment: @DavidW - it seems out of character to invent something this "useless"

Comment: This could have just been a prototype weapon. In testing the Kangas found it to be inefficient. The Trolls liked it. So they kept making it for them. Also this is one person's thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To They might not have been able to predict, when they started development, what the range, beam spread and effectiveness of the final product would be once fully engineered into a combat-hardened, field-repairable, personal small-arm.  It's not like that kind of failure is unusual (and not just with weapons).

Comment: We invent useless stuff all the time. We also create plenty of impracticale, or later decided to be impractical, weapons and armors. Dragonskin is considered to be too cost ineffective, as well as not providing an adequate protection increase in comparison to current body armors. Creating a weapon thinking it would be useful, and then deciding later "Nope. This one sucks" happens all the time. It would seem to me the Kanga made it, said it was junk, and the Trolls were so excited the Kanga kept making it just for them.

Comment: @Carson - "we" being the key word. Kangas are way different.

Comment: My point is, it's entirely possible that the Kanga didn't know ahead of time that the weapon would be impractical. They built it, tried it, didn't like it, and refused to use it, as pointed out by DavidW.